# Add own module/library to AOSP in separate Android.bp file

Tags: android, android-source, android-soong

I would like to build my own library during the AOSP build process and I'd like to be able to build the library with a stand-alone command, i.e., without building complete AOSP.

I've put the source files of my library into a separate folder and created an Android.bp file in there, but executing

`mmm path_to_folder/`

gives the error

```
FAILED: ninja: unknown target 'MODULES-IN-my-module'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mm MODULE_NAME -j$(nproc)` or `mm -j$(nproc)` inside your module folder.